# an integral problem during solving differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

During solving this complete differential equation:

$$(ye^x+e^y)dx+(e^x+xe^y)dy=0$$
$$u(x,y)= \int (ye^x+e^y)dx=\int ye^x dx + \int e^y dx$$
 this integral:

$$\int ye^x dx$$

both $e^{xy}$ and $ye^x$ are answer, I Should chose Which one? both works?

Comment: Why would the answer be $e^{xy}$? The derivative would be $ye^{xy}\ne ye^x$.

Comment: Oh true I missed that

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that both functions are primitives. To evaluate the $$\int ye^x\mathrm dx$$ is easy since you're integrating with respect to $x$ only, so you may factor out the constant $y,$ to get $$y\int e^x\mathrm dx=ye^x+\text{constant}.$$